Flutter GridView with PageScrollPhysics: Prevent Grid Items from Cropping on Page Scroll
I'm working on a Flutter app where I need to display items in a horizontally scrolling gridview. I want the [tag:GridView ]to behave like a paginated view, where each "page" scrolls exactly by one set of items (like a pageview), but I’m running into issues with items getting cropped.
PageviewPhysic scroll to item crop issue image
I set up my gridviewwith pagescrollphysics to achieve a paginated scroll effect, and my grid is set to display items in a 3x3 format. However, when I scroll, the next "page" starts midway through an item, resulting in the items getting partially cropped on the left side.
Here's my current code:
GridView.builder(
            // controller: controller,
            physics: PageScrollPhysics(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: 9,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              childAspectRatio: 2 / 8.80,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10,
              crossAxisSpacing: 0,
              crossAxisCount: 3,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Row(
                children: [
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/appicon.png'),
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 5),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "App Name",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          height: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "App Type",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          ),

Expected Behavior
I want each "page" scroll in the GridView to display exactly 3 columns per page and snap neatly to the beginning of the next set of grid items, without any items being cropped or partially displayed.

What you seek I think is a PageView. PageView animates between pages in similar fashion with the example in the link you provided.
Wrap your GridView with a PageView like in this example.


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Horizontal GridView Pagination',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Horizontal GridView Pagination'),
        ),
        body: PaginatedHorizontalGrid(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PaginatedHorizontalGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  // Sample list of items for the grid
  final List<String> items = List.generate(20, (index) => 'Item ${index + 1}');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Calculate the number of pages needed, with 3 items per page
    int pageCount = (items.length / 3).ceil();

    return PageView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: pageCount,
      itemBuilder: (context, pageIndex) {
        // Calculate the starting index for each page
        int startIndex = pageIndex * 3;
        // Get the subset of items for the current page
        List<String> pageItems = items.skip(startIndex).take(3).toList();

        return GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 1, // 1 row
            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
            childAspectRatio: 1.5, // Adjust as needed for item size
          ),
          itemCount: pageItems.length,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                pageItems[index],
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}



